# Windows 2008 R2 Scheduled Task

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Someone scheduled a task on Windows 2008 R2 which runs in the midnight.It Runs some Java program or Probably Visual Basic EXE to pull data from a different FTP to local server.

I am a programmer.

When I go to the task scheduler i don't see that task running i spent many hours on to figure it out which exe is being called and where that EXE is but did not help.

[image]

I checked in event viewer and the only this is what i see, so how do i find which exe is being called off where the event is and what time its scheduled

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the "Task Scheduler Library", click on the task in question, then go to the actions tab, which will show what is happening and what parameters.  In your case the "meat" of what is happening is probably parameters passed to cmd.exe.

I've used Windows Task Scheduler for 3 years now and never used "Running Tasks".

EDIT:  This is from Windows 7, but I believe Windows Server 2008 has the same Task Scheduler/UI.

[image: task scheduler]

Comment: I did that but see this http://i.imgur.com/8v3POZI.png which doesnt give me any idea on the mappings and the parameters

Comment: That's a picture of event viewer, look in task scheduler itself.